# Renaming a file along with extension in Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have uploaded a file as `filename.txt`, I wanted to rename it as `filename.java` so I executed this code

```
File file = new File();
file.Title = "filename.java";
FilesResource.PatchRequest request = service.Files.Patch(file, fileId);
File updatedFile = request.Execute();
```

File has been updated with new title as `filename.java`. But When I am downloading this file, the file name appears as `filename.java.txt`. So why is it adding extension of previous file name to updated file name? And How to overcome this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906926/how-do-i-stop-file-extension-being-remembered-and-applied-on-download-from-googl this might help.

Comment: @LIUFA ,Copy and Delete works fine and fullfil my requirement. But it would be more practical if we can rename file along its extension directly.

Comment: You could raise a ticket to google drive team, to add this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The fileExtension is [documented to be read-only and determined at creation time](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files):

> `fileExtension` `string` The file extension used when downloading this file. This field is read only. To set the extension, include it on title when creating the file. This is populated only for files with content stored in Drive.

Comment: Yes I now, but I want to rename file along with its extension. As  LIUFA pointed, It can be done by copying original file with new Name and deleting original file. But It would be great if we can do it directly.